# Package glossaries errors

Tags: glossaries

I wanted to use a glossary for the first time. I choose to go with the `glossaries` package and imported it with:

```
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}
```

and later used the

```
\makeglossaries
```

command and wanted to print the acronyms short after the table of contents with:

```
\printglossary[type=acronymtype]
```

Therefore I created a file with all acronyms in it right before the print statement. 
Then nothing was shown, in the glossary. So I went on, and used some entries in the document (text and headlines of sections).

My file structure is a main file with one included LaTeX document for every chapter. So I included the file the the acronyms in the main file and wanted to use them in  the included LaTeX documents. The acronyms were imported before the LaTeX files.

But now I get the error message:

```
Glossary entry: '...' has not been defined
```

What I have checked: names of the files are correct. 
Tested to include the acronym list also to in the files for the chapters.

Did a short web search. Does anyone have an idea where such an error might come from?

---

Update:

I found the error, why the document did not compile. I used `\include` instead of `\input` for importing the acronym file. Here is a minimal example:

main file:

```
 % This file is public domain
 % If you want to use arara, you need the following directives:
 % arara: pdflatex
 % arara: makeglossaries
 % arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{apple}{name={apple},description={a fruit}}

\begin{document}

\input{acronyms.tex}
\author{my Name}
\title{Glossary Test}
\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\chapter{\acrlong{xml}}
\Gls{apple} or \gls{apple} or \glspl{apple}.


\end{document}
```

The imported file has following lines:

```
\newacronym{autosar}{AUTOSAR}{AUTomotive Open System ARchitecture}
\newacronym{xml}{XML}{Extensible Markup Language}
```

The problem that is left over is, that neither the used nor the unused acronyms are showing up in a glossary.

Attempts to solve the problem:

1. I normaly use `xelatex` as processor, but a change to `pdflatex` did not change anything.
2. Also defining the acronmys in the main file did not change anything.

I hope, that is description may help to solve the problem.

Comment: Start with [`mwe-gls.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/mwe-gls.tex) or [`mwe-acr.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/mwe-acr.tex) or [`mwe-acr-desc.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/mwe-acr-desc.tex). Then try adding a few more of sample entries to demonstrate the problems you're experiencing and add the *complete minimal* test file to your question.

Comment: Hi @NicolaTalbot I just added an update! To the initial question.

Answer (score 6):

First move [`\input{acronyms}` to the preamble](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs) and delete the `.glsdefs` file.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{apple}{name={apple},description={a fruit}}

\input{acronyms.tex}% input somewhere before \begin{document}

\begin{document}

\author{my Name}
\title{Glossary Test}
\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\chapter{\acrlong{xml}}
\Gls{apple} or \gls{apple} or \glspl{apple}.

\end{document}
```

If the document is called, say, `myDoc.tex` then the complete document can be built with¹:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

or

```
xelatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
xelatex myDoc
xelatex myDoc
```

This shows the list of acronyms containing just the `xml` entry, because the `autosar` entry hasn't been indexed in the document.

[image: Acronyms XML Extensible Markup Language. 3, 7]

The location list includes page 3 (after a rebuild) because `\acrlong{xml}` is in the table of contents (which is on page 3). To avoid that, use the optional argument of `\chapter` with one of the non-indexing commands:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{apple}{name={apple},description={a fruit}}

\input{acronyms.tex}% input somewhere before \begin{document}

\begin{document}

\author{my Name}
\title{Glossary Test}
\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\chapter[\glsentrylong{xml}]{\acrlong{xml}}
\Gls{apple} or \gls{apple} or \glspl{apple}.

\end{document}
```

Now only page 5 appears in the location list:

[image: Acronyms XML Extensible Markup Language. 5]

If you want the unused entries to also appear in the list (without an associated page number) add `\glsaddallunused` *at the end of the document*.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{apple}{name={apple},description={a fruit}}

\input{acronyms.tex}% input somewhere before \begin{document}

\begin{document}

\author{my Name}
\title{Glossary Test}
\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\chapter[\glsentrylong{xml}]{\acrlong{xml}}
\Gls{apple} or \gls{apple} or \glspl{apple}.

\glsaddallunused % force indexing for all unused entries
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, in this case `xml` has been indexed but it hasn't been marked as used (`\gls` both indexes and marks an entry as used, but `\acrlong` only indexes), so `xml`'s location list goes wrong (in this case it disappears, but in other cases you can end up with a spurious comma):

[image: Acronyms AUTOSAR AUTomotive Open System ARchitecture. XML Extensible Markup Language.]

If you add `\gls{xml}` anywhere in the document (before `\glsaddallunused`), the problem will go away, otherwise you need to explicitly mark it as used:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{apple}{name={apple},description={a fruit}}

\input{acronyms.tex}% input somewhere before \begin{document}

\begin{document}

\author{my Name}
\title{Glossary Test}
\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\chapter[\glsentrylong{xml}]{\acrlong{xml}}
\glsunset{xml}% mark xml as used

\Gls{apple} or \gls{apple} or \glspl{apple}.

\glsaddallunused
\end{document}
```

[image: Acronyms AUTOSAR AUTomotive Open System ARchitecture. XML Extensible Markup Language. 5]

The default `main` glossary (containing `apple`) doesn't appear in the document because `\printglossary` has only been used with `type=\acronymtype`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{apple}{name={apple},description={a fruit}}
\newglossaryentry{pear}{name={pear},description={another fruit}}

\input{acronyms.tex}% input somewhere before \begin{document}

\begin{document}

\author{my Name}
\title{Glossary Test}
\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]% list of acronyms
\printglossary % main glossary

\chapter[\glsentrylong{xml}]{\acrlong{xml}}
\glsunset{xml}% mark xml as used

\Gls{apple} or \gls{apple} or \glspl{apple}.

\glsaddallunused
\end{document}
```

I've added another entry `pear` but haven't used it in the document, but `\glsaddallunused` automatically adds it, so the glossary looks like:

[image: Glossary apple a fruit. 5 pear another fruit.]

You can limit `\glsaddallunused` to a particular sub-set of lists with the optional argument, which should be a comma-separated list of labels identifying the required glossaries:

```
\glsaddallunused[\acronymtype]
```

Here's an alternative method using the [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package. This internally loads `glossaries` and automatically implements the `toc` and `nopostdot` options. (Use `postdot` or `nopostdot=false` to make the post-description full stop reappear.) The extension package also provides some commands specifically for use in chapter/section arguments, such as `\glsfmtshort` and `\glsfmtlong`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newglossaryentry{apple}{name={apple},description={a fruit}}
\newglossaryentry{pear}{name={pear},description={another fruit}}

\input{acronyms.tex}% input somewhere before \begin{document}

\begin{document}

\author{my Name}
\title{Glossary Test}
\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]% list of acronyms
\printglossary % main glossary

\chapter{\glsfmtlong{xml}}

First use \gls{xml}. Next use \gls{xml}.

\Gls{apple} or \gls{apple} or \glspl{apple}.

\glsaddallunused[\acronymtype] % add all unused entries from the acronym list
\end{document}
```

[image: Chapter 1 Extensible Markup Language First use Extensible Markup Language (XML). Next use XML. Apple or apple or apples.]

Outside of section headings, the short form is obtained with `\glsxtrshort` (not `\acrshort`), the long form is obtained with `\glsxtrlong` (not `\acrlong`) and the full form (without reference to the first use) is obtained with `\glsxtrfull` (not `\acrfull`).

If you don't want *long* (*short*) then change the abbreviation style to whatever form you will use most. For example, if you only want the short form except in the chapter heading then use the `short` style. This way you can use `\gls` to ensure that the entry is marked as used:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{short}

\newglossaryentry{apple}{name={apple},description={a fruit}}
\newglossaryentry{pear}{name={pear},description={another fruit}}

\input{acronyms.tex}% input somewhere before \begin{document}

\begin{document}

\author{my Name}
\title{Glossary Test}
\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]% list of acronyms
\printglossary % main glossary

\chapter{\glsfmtlong{xml}}

First use \gls{xml}. Next use \gls{xml}.

\Gls{apple} or \gls{apple} or \glspl{apple}.

\glsaddallunused[\acronymtype] % add all unused entries from the acronym list
\end{document}
```

For a full list of available abbreviation styles, see [sample-abbr-styles.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/samples/sample-abbr-styles.pdf).

[image: Chapter 1 Extensible Markup Language First use XML. Next use XML. Apple or apple or apples.]

If you want all defined entries listed, without page numbers, in the order of definition, then you can omit `\makeglossaries` and `\glsaddallunused` and replace `\printglossary` with `\printunsrtglossary`. (This option is only available with `glossaries-extra`):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newglossaryentry{apple}{name={apple},description={a fruit}}
\newglossaryentry{pear}{name={pear},description={another fruit}}

\input{acronyms.tex}% input somewhere before \begin{document}

\begin{document}

\author{my Name}
\title{Glossary Test}
\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\printunsrtglossary[type=\acronymtype]% list of acronyms
\printunsrtglossary % main glossary

\chapter{\glsfmtlong{xml}}

First use \gls{xml}. Next use \gls{xml}.

\Gls{apple} or \gls{apple} or \glspl{apple}.

\end{document}
```

The document build is now simplified to:

```
pdflatex myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

or

```
xelatex myDoc
xelatex myDoc
```

[image: Acronyms AUTOSAR AUTomotive Open System ARchitecture XML Extensible Markup Language]

---

¹The very first instance requires a rerun of the above because the page numbers will be off due to the missing list of acronyms on the first run. This isn't a problem if the list is at the end of the document or if the page numbering is reset after the list. For example, if you use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`:

```
\begin{document}

\author{my Name}
\title{Glossary Test}
\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]% list of acronyms
\mainmatter
```

Comment: At first I want to thank @nicola for you long answer. But I have a short question and a not. The question  is concerning the example code. When I removed the \newpage command and build the latex document as you purposed I still got empty pages in between. Secondly I created a short script to call the commands and added a line that calls bitex. Normally did have to do that. The bibliography has been build and used when compiled form the IDE. But now not anymore. So I have call bibtex by myself.

Comment: Additionally when I call makeglossaries, I get the warning that: File 'main.glo' is empty.:String

Comment: @OrdensRitter The warning is because the default `main` glossary is empty. If you use the `acronym` package option and only use `\newacronym` but not `\newglossaryentry` then no entries get added to the `main` glossary. If you don't require it add the `nomain` package option to prevent its creation. If you have any other problems you can ask a follow-up question and link back to this.

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same problem, removing `acronym` from the `\chapter` parameter. That solved the issue. But it may not be the best solution.